# How to add filters to a Grails app

Tags: grails, servlet-filters

I'm trying to add these [single signout filters](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+Single+Sign+Out) to my Grails 2.3.6 app. According to the [Grails docs on Filters](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#filters) it seems like you can only add new (custom) filters to Grails apps, whereas these are existing filters imported from another project/JAR.

I scanned my project for the existence of a `web.xml` and didn't find anything.

How can I add the specific filters in the above link to my Grails app?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run "`grails install-templates`" and edit the resulting `src/templates/war/web.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WebXmlConfig`](http://grails.org/plugin/webxml) plugin which provides a DSL approach to add/modify contents to `web.xml`.