# Include more than one filter from existing JAR into a Grails project

Tags: grails

I have a Grails project and want to add existing filters from a JAR file.

I used the `WebXmlConfig` plugin, mentioned in this answer:

[How to add filters to a Grails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996029/how-to-add-filters-to-a-grails-app)

and that worked great for a single filter, but I can't figure out how to extend that to more than one filter.

Do I need to change approach and edit the web.xml template directly?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [pluginator](http://grails.org/plugin/pluginator) plugin and put the definitions in `doWithWebDescriptor` just like you would in a plugin - you can add as many elements as you want.  It's a slick plugin that lets apps do things that are generally only supported in plugins, like conveniently editing web.xml (although with a seriously weird DSL) and registering custom artifact types.

Comment: Good suggestion but GPL is a deal-killer for me

Comment: I'm not a fan of GPL myself. But my understanding is that GPL would only affect you if you change the plugin's code, but even then you just need to make your changes available. If you just use it, you don't need to distribute anything or open your code. Affero GPL would be different - using that requires that you open-source your site code, and that's understandably a dealbreaker in many cases.

Comment: That sounds like the LGPL.  The GPL is viral to some extent, by design.  I don't know how it applies in this case, to a plug-in used at build time without a runtime dependency.